# Understanding projection, extent and scale in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, scale, display

I am creating a map using QGIS that has shapefiles in different projections. I was able to reproject them to the correct ESPG code that I need, however they do not line up.  My base layer "illinois state plane zones" has the extents; 
North: 42.508347916666146
West: -91.51351833333352
South: 36.969971916666374
East: -87.49521391666703

Scale: 119:1

The layer that is not lining up correctly has extents in different units, so I can understand why they will not overlay each other, but how can I rectify this?

I have re-projected and that doesn't seem to help.

Layer 02062019 Extents are:
North: 1801408.0041401046
West: 1196576.2196446825
South: 1799584.9969252362
East: 1198603.4151709464

Scale:1:2543

Also the scales don't match.

Can I georeference a shapefile to another shapefile to correct this issue, at least as far as the scale issue is concerned?

Re-projecting didn't seem to help at all and I need to figure this out.

What could be causing the extent problem?

Comment: What are the EPSG codes of the data originally, projected and canvas? You shouldn't need to georeference or adjust your data; by how much does the data misalign to your other data? Differing units shouldn't matter provided the units are defined correctly in the coordinate reference system, QGIS should be able to *project on the fly* to account for different units and datums. You do have project on the fly enabled in QGIS don't you?

Comment: @Heather, welcome to GIS SE! + Read [this QGIS manual section](https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_projections/working_with_projections.html). + Reproject both layers _(Layer -> Save as)_ to the same CRS. + Render the canvas _(Project -> Properties -> CRS)_ to the same CRS too. + [Edit your question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/posts/311983/edit) to include appropriate information (CRS used) and the results obtained.

Comment: @ Michael, I do have OTF enabled.  The data doesn't even show up in the same area on the map canvas, i have to right click, "zoom to layer" to find it, then do the same to get back to the base layer I am trying to get it to align with. I have manually updated the extents, i have reprojected so that they are all in the same CRS, I have tried to use a different CRS and allow OTF to do the work, nothing has worked to get these layer in the area to be workable together.

Comment: @Gabriel, I will try and update once I get a resolve in doing this or not! Thank you!